# Autocomment ''' in VisualStudio 2008 stopped working - how to enable it again?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

The auto-comment option in my Visual Studio 2008 suddenly stopped working. o_O
Does anybody know how to repair it and enable this feature again?
I'm putting triple apostrophe above function and comment tags do not appear. :(
I was trying to reset vs settings but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like XML document generation is turned off in your project.  This causes the XML comments (triple apostrphe's) to stop working.

To re-enable it try the following

- Right click on the project and select **Properties**
- Go to the **Compile** Tab
- Check "Generate XML documentation file"